# How insert a 3D viewer into java application for .obj file?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, java-8, .obj

I created a simple Java application using JavaFX. I would like to integrate a 3D viewer on my window with which I can interact with the mouse (only to rotate the 3D object).

Is it possible to achieve such a thing in Java with JavaFX?

The purpose of my project would be to display a 3D object from a .obj file.

I use java 8 and I looked at Java 3D but I can not find many examples on the Internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all possible with JavaFX which directly supports some 3D graphics.

Start with a general tutorial here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm

and then use the model loaders from here:
http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html